# How to tell if my raspberry PI is working (Home assistant USB booting)?

Tags: pi-3, usb, usb-power

I am trying to run HA on a Raspberry PI 3B via USB but I am having a lot of issues.

**My Setup:**

- Raspberry PI 3B
- SATA to USB adapter with external power
- 500GB SATA SSD
- 5V 3A Power supply (up to 20V in fast charging)
- For loading the image on the SSD I tried both the official raspberry PI imager and Balena etcher, both with no result. (I am on Windows)
- Home Assistant 11.4

**Issue:**

When the Raspberry PI gets powered on, the ACT light blinks once, then the activity light on the SSD blinks few times, then nothing, ever again. The ACT light stays off, and so does the SSD activity light.

Even after 20 minutes, I still cannot access homeassistant, so I thought there was an issue with booting, but here comes the weird part:

On my gateway dashboard I see a device called homeassistant after a couple minutes of it being on, and I **can ping it**.
However, to add to the weirdness, if I run

```
nmap -sP -PE [ip_address]
```

It returns `host is down`

Also, the ethernet port of the RPI starts blinking right after it is on, and stays this way indefinitely.

I also tried reaching it from `ip_address:8123`, but nothing.

I also have no monitor output (this was also the case when I was using Raspberry PI OS, so I guess my monitor is incompatible)

I also would like to add that I did not change any coniguration to the raspberry PI, other than enabling usb booting via this command:

```
echo program_usb_boot_mode=1 | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt
```

Which I know works because I can boot via USB the raspberry PI OS with no problems, and because I have verified via:

```
vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 17:
```

I am not sure what to do, as I cannot tell where the issue is...
Does no ACT light mean anything if you are not using an SD card?
If it is not booting, I assume the ethernet port lights should not be active? Is this an issue with my network configuration?

**UPDATE:** I managed to find a monitor to connect that works, and I get a red (UBOOT) screen on a quarter of the monitor that is extremely hard to read. (It tries to set the resolution to 1000 x 5000)

This is what I can decipher from it:

```
...
Device 0: Unkown device

Device 0: unkown device
Waiting for ethernet connection... done
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
BOOTP broadcast 3
*** something option is number
DHCP client something to address 192.168.1.135 (number in ms)
*** no boot? file name: 
Using smsc95xx_eth device?
From server 192.168.1.1: our IP address is 192.168.1.135
Filename 'numbers.something'
Loading TTTTTTTT
Retry count exceeded: starting again 
Retrying file
Waiting for ethernet connection
Using something_eth device?
File name pelinux.cly [pxelinux.cfg?]
Load [memory address I presume]
Loading TTTTTTTT
Retry count exceeded: starting again 
Retrying file
Waiting for ethernet connection
Using smsc95xx_eth device?
From server 192.168.1.1: our IP address is 192.168.1.135
Filename pxelinux.something
```

[image: I cannot really read much]

Comment: You need to plug in a monitor that works or gain access remotely (eg. via SSH), otherwise you are just wasting your time.

Comment: Just to confirm. 1. You are using the RPi3 version of HA, and 2. Have you tried using an SD card for HA, just to rule out some weird HA setup that may not expect to boot from a USB drive; and 3. You've booted Raspberry Pi OS from the same drive you are trying to use for HA?

Comment: @goldilocks how do I access via SSH? I thought it was not possible without the add-on, or is there some config file I can put in the USB drive that allows me to connect? I actually have also tried my TV, but still no result... Do you think it is booting?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes j am using the version for RPI3, I have tried using an SD card for it, and it worked! Also yes, I have used the exact same drive/PSU/adapted ro successfully run RPI OS

Comment: so, the only thing that doesn't work is HA on USB Drive - most likely some part of the HA image expects it to be on `/dev/mmcblk0` - it's not the first Raspberry Pi image to be poorly created

Comment: You can enable SSH by modifying the SD card (or whatever boot medium), but you will need a system that can access an ext4 filesystem, which vanilla Windows cannot; I think the usual solution there is to install a linux VM.   Home Assistant looks to be Debian derived like RpiOS, so what you need to do is create a symlink from `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service` into `/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants`.   This may be hamstrung if home assistant uses a firewall.   But what I really recommend is that you beg borrow or steal a regular HD flatscreen with HDMI and plug that and keyboard in.

Comment: @goldilocks thank you! I managed to find a monitor, and updated the post with what I get

Comment: @JaromandaX but I have tried recreating the image multiple times.. I updated the post with more details, since I managed to connect a functioning screen

Comment: Is there anything usual about that monitor?  If it's a reasonably normal HDMI LCD screen  built in the last 5-10 years and supports normal HD (1920 x 1080), attached with a single cable <= 6' long, it shouldn't look like that unless the resolution is set to something weird in `config.txt` (I did read your comment about this).   WRT the messages, I'm guessing that's some implemented by Home Assistant.    If you really had this working properly off an SD card, maybe you should just go back to that -- HA doesn't seem like that kind of application that's going to benefit from faster storage.

Comment: my statement that `it's not the first Raspberry Pi image to be poorly created` was not a criticism of you, but of the people who create the images that assume what device an end user will be using

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah that makes sense, I can try with a different HDMI cable as well perhaps... The reason why I wanted to use an SSD is to not have my SD card die after a very short time, since many HA users have suffered that issue

Comment: WRT to SD card corruption issues, keep in mind: 1) These were much more frequent with the first few Pi models, so always check the date etc. on these reports, 2) If "many" means a number of reports (dozens or even hundreds), this may still be a small minority  vs. "many" meaning a high percentage of users (which I presume is not what you meant)...

Comment: ...Anyway, generally speaking the long term regulars here report not having these kinds of problems, and case in point, I've had about a dozen different Pis over the past 10+ years, I've only ever used an SD card for the root filesystem, and I've never had a significant problem with corruption.  But people who do not have a problem do not post regularly to internet forums going on about how everything is fine.  Right now, I'd say in order to avoid what might be more or less a superstition, you've created a real problem for yourself.

Comment: You are really right! Luckily I managed to find an okay middle ground. I boot HA from SD nornally, and I have mounted the SSD as datadisk. I configured it so that it stores the DB on the SSD while keeping the OS on the SD

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution, but what I ended up doing, and recommend at this point if you too are having issues, is to use both SD and SSD.

Install HA on the SD card and boot from there, so you solve yourself quite some problems, as this is the intended way.

Then, to address the issue with short SD card lifespan and increase performance, connect the SSD as well, and, once everything is installed, run "move data disk".
This way, HA will run the DB on the SSD while keeping the OS on the SD card.